# using a regression model in r to predict a dataset

Tags: r, regression, predict

I am trying to use a dataset to create a regression model and then use a test dataset to test it.

My code is as follow (my data has 112 row so I am using 90 row to training and the rest for testing):

```
model_data=mydata[1:90,]
test_data=my_data[91:112,]

model=lm(model_data$`p-0q` ~ model_data$`p-1-q`+ 
            model_data$p2 +model_data$p3,model_data$p4                 
            ,data=model_data)

predict(model, newdata = test_data)-> test_result
```

When I run this model, I am getting this warning

```
Warning: 'newdata' had 22 rows but variables found have 90 rows
Warning in predict.lm(model, newdata = test_data) :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading
```

How can I interpret test_result to see if it is a good fit (comparing test_reasult with real values that I have)?

Comment: Remove `model_data$` from the formula within the `lm` call.

Comment: Roland is right, if you have `data=model_data` then the `lm` function will directly identify you formula variables

Comment: @Roland The problem is that column names are strange, something such as p-12w, which means I can not use them directly. See updated code.

Comment: \`p-0q\` ~ \`p-1-q\`+ p2 + p3 is perfectly valid syntax in R. The `predict` method needs to take these variables from your test data. That is not possible if you hard-code your training data in the model specification.

Comment: However, I would rename the columns in `model_data` to valid names.

Comment: @Roland Thanks that was solved the problem (It is my fault as I am a C/C++ and Python developer and not familiar with R syntax). Can you please help me with the second question?  (How can I interpret test_result to see if it is a good fit (comparing test_reasult with real values that I have)?)

Comment: That's not a programming question. Consult a statistician. (You might be happy with calculating the root mean squared error.)

Comment: In your model, you wrote : "model_data$p3,model_data$p4". You should write it : "p3 + p4"